# Where do the "Allow in the Background" login items in the macOS Ventura System Settings come from?

Tags: macos, mac, launchd, login-items, ventura

I have some mysterious entries in the **Login Items > Allow in the Background** section in the macOS Ventura System settings.

How can I find out more information about them, such as their command-line arguments?

[image: The Login Items page in the macOS Ventura System Settings]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get much more verbose output about all startup items simultaneously on the command line with `sfltool dumpbtm`.  The output is fairly self-explanatory, but the tool itself seems almost completely undocumented.

Objective See has [a slightly more featureful and documented version](https://github.com/objective-see/DumpBTM) that is also open source (compiled binaries can be downloaded from the [release page](https://github.com/objective-see/DumpBTM/releases)).  That tool's README also explains the new consolidation of the various types of login items (LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, login items).

Comment: (You do need to `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine dumpBTM` after downloading it, but presumably if you're manually slinging binaries around, you can manage that)

Comment: Thank you! `sfltool dumpbtm` revealed that apps in Trash still appear on the "Allow in the Background" list.

Comment: Once you run `sfltool dumpbtm`, how do you remove items from the list?

Comment: I did run across documentation for the ```sfltool``` in a section on platform deployment: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/deployment/depdca572563/web

Answer (score 13):

In my specific case the "Allow in the Background" login items are coming from `/Library/LaunchAgents`

---

Other login related are

- Applications that run on Startup

  - `ls -lah /Library/StartupItems`
- Property list (plist) items running on startup

  - `ls -lah /Library/LaunchDaemons`
  - `ls -lah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons`
- Applications that launch on User Login

  - `ls -lah /Library/LaunchAgents`
  - `ls -lah ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
  - `ls -lah /System/Library/LaunchAgents`
- Applications that run on a set schedule

  - `crontab -l`
- Kernel Extensions

  - `kextstat`
- Login and Logout Hooks

  - `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`
  - `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook`

Comment: Which of these are reflected as "Allow in the background" items?

Comment: Hi @nohillside you find "Allow in the background" items into `/Library/LaunchAgents` those are Applications that launch on User Login

Comment: Problem is that I have "Allow in the background" items which show up in none of the LaunchAgents/LauchDaemons directories (and don't even have an (i) icon to click on).

Comment: Paste into a terminal the lines you see in my answer, then share those output and also a screenshot of your Login Items Allow in the Background, for sure is somewhere there

Comment: For the people who are in this thread and have deleted apps and files from the above mentioned directories. Make sure you empty your trash too :)

Answer (score 9):

Some items in the list (but not all) have a 'circle i' info button: ⓘ which you can click to reveal their location in the Finder.

In addition to the `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons` folders in `/Library` and `~/Library`, applications may have items inside their bundle, e.g. inside:

`/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/`
`/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Library/LaunchAgents/`
`/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

which show up in the list.

However, I still have some items whose location I have not been able to identify, so other locations may also be involved.

As to command-line arguments: it's unlikely that such executables will have documentation for users, so apart from calling them with `--help` or similar, you'd have to search the binary for strings.

Answer (score 4):

These items are [`launchd` Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

The linked documentation describes the location and format of their defining property list files. Launch Daemons and Agents defined in `/System/Library` are not shown in the System Settings.

The relevant files can be found in the following locations:

- `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
- `~/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
- `/Library/LaunchAgents/`
- `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

Answer (score -1):

For short,
`sfltool dumpbtm` show info.
`sfltool resetbtm` reset database (to clean up uninstalled but still listed apps)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer probably would work better as an edit to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457725/9058.

Comment: don't try `sfltool resetbtm`. it removes all there `Open at Login` items.

Comment: Just `sfltool dumpbtm`, find and remove unwanted items. `URL` and `Executable Path`

Comment: I executed `sfltool resetbtm` and they all came back when I rebooted