# Allow in the Background Unrecognized Entry

Tags: macbook-pro, malware, multitasking

I have a mysterious entry called "Denis Graur", does anybody have clue of what it is from? It does sound like I might be infected with a malware.
[image]

Comment: He's listed as a developer of CactusVPN. Ever used that?

Comment: I believe I have, a long time ago. Thankfully it doesn't sound like malware, just old files. I just can't find where it's located, it's not in the locations mentioned in this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449441/where-do-the-allow-in-the-background-login-items-in-the-macos-ventura-system-s

Comment: There's a list of locations in this [it may be out of date, I can't check newest macOS] - https://superuser.com/a/969821/347380

Answer (score 4):

I have seen references in post-Ventura updates to software that uses Application and Helper tools not having them registered using the proper application names, but using the developer name instead. It seems this may be the same situation affecting your installation of CactusVPN, and that a developer update might be needed. Something changed in Ventura no doubt.

An example I saw yesterday was in an update to Backup Loupe (to v3.8.1). The text:

```
macOS Ventura: Application and helper tools do not appear as BackupLoupe in the Login Items section of General tab of System Settings
```

I've two more like that on my system, but luckily I recognise the developer's name.

https://soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/ReleaseNotes.html