# What is this Login Item - Allow in the Background?

Tags: startup, daemons

It is listed as Mark Allan, I imagine the software author or company.
[image]

Comment: See my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/450884/221742 It appears to be some issue in Ventura where the developer name is registered instead of the App name. Luckily my answer hasn't yet been upvoted, or I would have marked your question as a duplicate.

Comment: I think we ought to link these as dupes, as it appears to be the same underlying issue -  [Allow in the Background Unrecognized Entry](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450884/allow-in-the-background-unrecognized-entry)

Comment: @Tetsujin Respectfully I disagree -- the question is clearly "what is this login item", and that is not answered in the specific sense (ClamXAV), only in the generic sense (some apps have the developer name), nor does it provide a mechanism for discovering who Mark Allen is.

Comment: @DavidMcKee - you say that as though linking them was a *bad* thing. It isn't, it's a good thing; it lets people find an answer from multiple routes, different searches. This is a Ventura bug, so it crops up in many guises… one for each developer name.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Allan is the author/founder of [ClamXAV](https://clamxav.com/about-us/), Mac Antivirus software.

I grepped the system, particularly looking at:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/
/Library/LaunchAgents/
~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Couple of the launch services in the above pointed to the same matches here:

```
grep --recursive --ignore-case "allan" /Applications/ClamXAV.app/Contents/Library/
Binary file /Applications/ClamXAV.app/Contents/Library//LaunchServices/uk.co.canimaansoftware.ClamXAV.HelperToolUpdater matches
Binary file /Applications/ClamXAV.app/Contents/Library//LaunchServices/uk.co.canimaansoftware.ClamXAV.HelperTool matches
```

The results of the following checked out with the above.

```
grep --recursive --ignore-case "clam" /Library/LaunchDaemons
```