# "Joel Rennich" "Le Liu" Background programs

Tags: macos, malware

As you can see below, I got these prompts when I startup my Mac. What are these programs with people's names **"Joel Rennich"** and **"Le Liu"** on my Mac.

How Can I find and get rid of them?

[image: Joel Rennich][image: Le Liu]

[image: Login Items]

Comment: These are likely the authors of software you have installed.  Some software is written by individuals, and on macOS, lots of software is signed with a certificate issued to the developer by Apple.  JetBrains is also an author of software, but they're a company instead of a human.

Comment: Do you happen to have Snipaste installed? https://github.com/Snipaste/feedback/issues/2366

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450923/221742