# Who's Nikita Borodulin from Settings > Login Items?

Tags: macos, settings, login-items

On macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a) in Settings, in Login Items there's an entry "Nikita Borodulin 3 items: 3 items affect all users". Who's this person?

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Possibly this bug has returned? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450884/allow-in-the-background-unrecognized-entry

Comment: http://hello.human.lv/en/?ct=23010110

Comment: @tetsujin was it ever gone?

Comment: @nohillside - idk, I just remember we had a few questions about it a while back, I didn't see mention of it in a while.

Comment: It's probably the name of a developer of software you've installed.

Comment: This isn't a bug and it's been present through all of Ventura - it is showing the developer name because of a defect in the apps packaging (versus what the system expects)

Comment: It's likely something this person has created, but I can't find anything in their repositories that would match so that is speculation: https://github.com/swasta